Unable to Elevate access for a Global Administrator with Azure Entra ID
I am trying to Elevate access for a Global Administrator in Azure.
I am following process highlighted in the following link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/role-based-access-control/elevate-access-global-admin?tabs=azure-portal
However, if you look at the image below, I'm not seeing the option to select anything for "Access management for Azure resources"

Can someone let me know what the additional permissions I need. I currently have 'Contributor' access.

To assign Global Administrator role to user Refer this MsDoc

Access management for Azure resource toggle is only available for those users who has  Global Administrator role assigned  in Microsoft Entra ID.

My actual reason for submitting this question is because I keep on getting the greyed out message Add role assignment(disable) when I try to 'Add' a role assignment. I thought this would be resolved by elevating to Global Administrator

Do you want to add role assignment at Subscription level?

@PratikJadhav, yes I want to add a role assignment, but I only have 'Contributor' access

To add role assignment you need Owner permission at Subscription level.

@PratikJadhav, will Global Administrator permission allow me to as a role assignment?

As Global administrator is Microsoft Entra roles it won't allow you to add role assignment at Subscription level. For Azure-built in roles, To add role assignment you should have Owner or User Access Administrator permission at Subscription level. Refer this MsDoc

With Contributor role, Won't able to add role assignment, You should have Owner or User Access Administrator role at Subscription level.


To Add role assignment at subscription level

Initially, I assigned Contributor role to one of the user and got same came across with same issue (greyed out Add role assignment):

**NOTE:  Contributor Grants full access to manage all resources, but does not allow you to assign roles in Azure RBAC.
To resolve this issue, You should have Azure built-in Role of Owner role or User Access Administrator role at Subscription level.
Owner: Grants full access to manage all resources, including the ability to assign roles in Azure RBAC.
I added User Access Administrator role at Subscription Level.

NOTE:  Azure roles control permissions to manage access to Azure resources, while Microsoft Entra roles control permissions to manage access Microsoft Entra resources.
Reference:
Azure-built-in Roles
Azure roles V/S Microsoft Entra Roles
